# node express server does not receives authorization from axios and got "access-control-request-headers: Authorization"

Tags: typescript, express, axios

I got a client project to test my services (i use axios, v.0.21):

```
    var auth = {
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'foo'
    };
    var re =  await axios.post(url,
    { 
        token: token
    },
    { 
        auth: auth
    }
    );
```

In server side, I obtain this:

[image]

I mean that in header i got "access-control-request-headers: Authorization", and the property authorization is empty (undefined). When I do this from Insomnia (tool for testing rest apis) I got the basic authorization propertly.

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORS issue.

Solved using this extension: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html